# getting started to ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, webserver, hosting

I had just downloaded ubuntu 12 now i and also installed but i don't know how to use it.

I want to host a complete website (online i.e., viewable in public) working website with php and mysql.

Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Use to install all in one packet mysql + apache2**

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

**if you need ruby + passanger use it (download and install rvm+ruby)**

```
    sudo su
      apt-get install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev git-core subversion imagemagick libmagickwand-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev 

  curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.0.0
```

**Activate ruby**

```
 source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

**Auto activate ruby rvm**

```
  echo '[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Install webserver with passanger mod ngnix/apache2**

```
gem install passenger --no-ri --no-rdoc
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

**Configiure ngnix**

```
 git clone git://github.com/jnstq/rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu.git
    mv rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu/nginx/nginx /etc/init.d/nginx
    chown root:root /etc/init.d/nginx
    update-rc.d nginx defaults
    nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

Comment: but how could i take my website online

Comment: you want to run a ubuntu server to your website, give the clear information to make review on your plans.